# How to generate a rendering of a preview snippet with both image and text like Facebook displays

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I would like to generate something to display that looks like the Facebook app previews using plain javascript. I already have the image url, title, and description data. However, I have no idea where to start with rendering exactly like the following:

[google maps preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LP6E.png)

Usually, how do you accomplish this in javascript? Do you have to manually specify the CSS? I'd really appreciate any advice and resource suggestions. I'm very new to javascript and UI.

Comment: In a nutshell the process would be something like: **a)** fetch the URL using AJAX. **b)** parse the response. **c)** extract the Open Graph meta tags to find title, description, and image. **d)** fallback to meta title, description and first image in source, if OG meta tags not specified. **e)** render custom styled preview

Comment: So, your question is about the layout and markup rendering?
Are you using some framework like react? Or are we talking for plain js?

Comment: Thanks for the steps. I edited my question to give some more context. I already have the open graph meta tags parsed. I am mainly wondering how to render the preview like Facebook does using plain js. Is this ui format something already available in javascript, or would I have to try to manually recreate the display to match their version?

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve], this is an extremely simple, basic, CSS related question, nothing to do with JS

Comment: If you already have the content for the preview, can you post the HTML and CSS that you've written to render the preview? This doesn't need to be with JavaScript at this stage, just the final HTML you expect to see on your page.

Answer (score 1):

So our goal is something like:

```
<div class="containerDiv">
    <img src="blah blah">
    <div>
       <div  class="urlDiv">my.url.com</div>
       <div class="titleDiv">My title</div>
       <div class="descriptionDiv">My description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will of course need to style a bit. Your page typically loads a lot of css style sheets. To one of them, you can add the css that will style your new "component". As an example:

```
<style>
    .containerDiv {
         display:flex;
         align-items:center;
         border:solid 1px gray;
         /* etc... */
    }

    .containerDiv > img { /*...style for the image...*/ }
    /*...more styles...*/
</style>
```

My answer will not include the correct css. Learning css in depth by is itself long proccess, so be patient. Follow a good CSS tutorial in case you need it.

Let's go on. The next step is to render the above markup with js.
To achieve this with plain js, use the native functions:

1) [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create a new element. This returns a js object containing the html element representation. This is not appended yet to the document. It is not visible, not yet a part of the page.

2) You can manipulate this object using: [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute). Attribute is everything that follows your tag name. For example, to set the src of an image call:

```
const myImg = document.createElement("img");
myImg.setAttribute("src", "https://my.cool/image.png"); //the image is still not visible, because we did not yet append it into the DOM...
```

3) We use [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) property and/or [append child](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) to add elements within other elements (you typically start by creating the outer most element, create each child one by one and call appendChild of the parent to add each child).

4) Once you are ready creating your whole element, append it anywhere you like in the document, and it will become visible:

```
const myCoolElement = document.createElement("div");
//do stuff
document.body.appendChild(myCoolElement); //this will put it at the end of the page

//or, alternativelly
document.querySelector(".myElement > #thatWillHost .my .newComponent").appendChild(myCoolElement); //to append it somewhere else.
```

As a side note, [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) will be also useful functions to you. Using querySelector, you can append your new element anywhere in the page that you like.

As a conclusion, you can react and manipulate the document through js by using tha mentioned (and many more) functions that are available out-of-the-box in every browser.